# How to pass multiple variables from a php file to ajax and use them?

Tags: javascript, php

I have read many answers on stack overflow but I can't find an apt answer. I want to send multiple variables from php file to a javascript file. I want to use those variables later separately. So please explain with a simple example of how to get the variables from php file and how to use them separately later.

This is my js.

```
<script>
function here(card_numb) {
    alert("pk!");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.php',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: ({
            card_number: card_numb
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('card_number:'+data.card_number+'book_issued:'+data.book_isued);

        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting the alert 'pk!'. But $.ajax ain't working.

This is details.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['card_number'])){
 $card_number = $_GET['card_number'];

 $query = "Select * from users where card_number = '".$card_number."'";
 $query_run = mysqli_query($link,$query);
 $row_numb =@mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
 if($row_numb == 0){
     echo "<div class='bdiv1'>No such number found!</div>";
 } else{

      $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
         $book1 = $row['user_name'];

    $arr = array('isued_book' => $book1,'card_number' => $card_number);
     echo json_encode($arr);

     exit();
 }
```

}
    ?>

Thank you!

Comment: what have done so far? We need your code.

Comment: Literally, I am facing a lot of problems while pasting a code here so I opt for asking the question in general

Comment: just try to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have  added the code

Comment: So not that many "problems while pasting a code here" then...

Comment: Please come to the point. Do you know the solution to the problem i have stated?..

Comment: did you get any error in you console ?

Answer (score 0):

somthing.js - ur jspage

```
<script>
function here(card_numb) {

$.ajax({
    url: 'details.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: {
        card_number: card_numb
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('card_number:'+data.card_number+'book_issued:'+data.isued_book);

    }
});
```

}
      success: function(result){
          console.log('variable1:'+result.var1+'variable2:'+result.var2+'variable3:'+result.var3);
      } });

details.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['card_number'])){
$card_number = $_GET['card_number'];
$query = "Select * from users where card_number = ".$card_number;
$query_run = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$row_numb =@mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
if(!$query_run){
   echo "<div class='bdiv1'>No such number found!</div>";
} else {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
    $book1 = $row['user_name'];

 $arr = array('isued_book' => $book1,'card_number' => $card_number);
 echo json_encode($arr);

 exit();
}
```

if the currect value get in $row you can get the result in console

Comment: It is not working. I did the same, please check the question again I have added the code.